# Why do some admissions applications ask where I've been living and what I've been doing for the last few years?

Tags: graduate-admissions

What are the intention of the question ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 20):

US state universities frequently charge lower tuition to in-state residents. The form states that if you do not fill in all the information requested, you will be classified as a non-resident and be charged the higher rate. Check the U of Utah's tuition system [here](http://admissions.utah.edu/cost/).

Comment: so in the below form, i would not need to write down anything as I am not a resident in the USA now?

Comment: So it would appear to me. To be on the safe side, you could contact the university and ask them. They will probably know more about their admission system than random strangers on Academia.SE...

Comment: @UnlimitedDreamer:  I'd fill in the country of legal residence rather than leaving it blank.  That makes it perfectly clear that you do not expect in-state tuition.

Answer (score 4):

As an alum of the school it appears you are applying to (University of Utah) I can confirm what Stephan Kolassa said about lower tuition for in-state residents.  One thing that should be mentioned is that after attending a specific university for a while *you may qualify as a resident of that state* and thus, after attending a university for a certain amount of time, you can eventually become a resident and be charged in-state resident tuition.  I don't know how this works for international students though.